# iOS Build error: exportArchive: Lunch.app requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3, provisioning-profile

I'm currently building a Ionic v.3 app that are almost done and we are trying to build the app for booth iOS and Android with the Ionic Pro service. I have setup Certificates for booth Android and iOS. But when i'm trying to build for ios i get a weird error in the build log.

Anyone have any clue what are going wrong and how to fix this issue?  I have already provided a provisioning profile. As I'm using the Ionic Pro , i'm building and packaging trough their webinterface. Booth certificate, provisioning profile and password is set up correct before the package process i started.

```
[20:56:50]: Generated plist file with the following values:
[20:56:50]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[20:56:50]: ▸ {
[20:56:50]: ▸   "provisioningProfiles": {
[20:56:50]: ▸     "864J5Y5PX8.com.kvartersmenyn.Dagenslunch": "Distribution"
[20:56:50]: ▸   },
[20:56:50]: ▸   "method": "app-store",
[20:56:50]: ▸   "signingStyle": "manual",
[20:56:50]: ▸   "teamID": "2T3D838Z6K"
[20:56:50]: ▸ }
[20:56:50]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[20:56:50]: $ /usr/bin/xcrun /Users/ionic/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.75.1/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist '/var/folders/9c/qg1skf6x65jdn7_5fqls39pr0000gn/T/gym_config20180129-433-1eu51ho.plist' -archivePath /Users/ionic/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-01-29/adf81fff-0e96-4efd-a771-bb9a3b7c662b-app-store\ 2018-01-29\ 20.55.40.xcarchive -exportPath '/var/folders/9c/qg1skf6x65jdn7_5fqls39pr0000gn/T/gym_output20180129-433-y79zaf' 
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/9c/qg1skf6x65jdn7_5fqls39pr0000gn/T/gym_config20180129-433-1eu51ho.plist -archivePath '/Users/ionic/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-01-29/adf81fff-0e96-4efd-a771-bb9a3b7c662b-app-store 2018-01-29 20.55.40.xcarchive' -exportPath /var/folders/9c/qg1skf6x65jdn7_5fqls39pr0000gn/T/gym_output20180129-433-y79zaf
2018-01-29 20:56:51.083 xcodebuild[1279:5015] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/9c/qg1skf6x65jdn7_5fqls39pr0000gn/T/Lunch_2018-01-29_20-56-51.082.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-01-29 20:56:51.831 xcodebuild[1279:5015] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
"Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"Lunch.app\" requires a provisioning profile.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"Lunch.app\" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: "Lunch.app" requires a provisioning profile.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""Lunch.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="Lunch.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
[20:56:51]: Exit status: 70
[20:56:51]: No provisioning profile provided
[20:56:51]: Make sure to pass a valid provisioning for each required target
[20:56:51]: Check out the docs on how to fix this: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/#export-options
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution found in this thread on Apple's developer site: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86933 ?

Answer (score 4):

I had this kind of issue. In my case...I choosed the provisioning profile and under yourtargetapp.plist...I found the provisioning profile param which has incorrect bundle identifier. After correcting the provisioning profile bundle id to my targetapp bundle id...this issue got resolved.